# The type HashMap is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, Integer>

Tags: java

This is a strange error i am getting today when i try to implement a Map as below.

```
Map<String, Integer> cache = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

I am using **JDK 1.7** and not sure why this error has been coming and changing the above line by adding cast removes the error. **I looked at the related posts in stackoverflow before posting this question seems to be strange issue.**

```
Map<String, Integer> cache = (Map<String, Integer>) new HashMap();
```

Comment: Are you sure both `Map` and `HashMap` come from `java.util` package in your code?

Comment: @Shane - What is the error ? Are you using any IDE like eclipse ?

Comment: Are you declaring your own non-generic `HashMap` class anywhere? Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I was getting the same error. In my case, I had given my class the same name i.e created a class labeled HashMap. This was conflicting with the java.util.HasMap. make sure your class name is different

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check you are actually using **java.util.HashMap** and **java.util.Map** in your **imports**.

Answer (score 8):

I have also gone through the same error but it was resolved just by changing some properties of the project:

- Right-click on your project
- Click on `Properties`
- Select `Java Build Path` from right-hand side panel
- Select `Order and Export` tab
- Click on your `JRE System Library or JDK Library`
- Click on `Up` button and move it to first position
- Click `Ok`
- Clean & build your project.

Do repeat this for all other dependents project as well, if you have dependencies.

It resolved my issue because previously the Java files were picking other libraries and packages not from JRE package as it was ordered set in last priority.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that you are importing the wrong `HashMap`. You have to use the `java.util` packages for the code you presented there.

We can't help you any further without seeing your import statements.

Answer (score 1):

The type HashMap is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, Integer>

If this type of error occur than first check your file name and class name
Beause by mistake you save file name as HashMap.java
Than try other ways

Comment: what do you mean by HashMap is not generic.
The definition of java.util.HashMap is:
public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V>

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solution works ,the only possible reason you are getting this error is because you might have named your class_name similar to an already existing class which is either in util or lang library .

Answer (score 0):

Never name or keep your class name same as any class which is predefined in Java Util.

For example: In Java `HashMap` is predefined class and if create a new class with same name i.e `HashMap` then it's obvious to get such error.

Comment: Welcome on SO. When answering to questions, try to adress the question, not other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have met the same problem.Almost I have found all the answers, but I failed.
I had imported **java.util.HashMap** and **java.util.Map** or set the **JRE System Library** to the **top**.But in vain.

At last, I tried to change my Class name from **HashMap** to **HashMapDemo**. Now, I just want to tell you that your Class name may be one of the java.util.*, you should change your Class name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have named your class with the same name as other class you can always do the following:

```
Map<String, Integer> cache = new java.util.HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

It's a common mistake when you are trying a new language/library capability to call the class with the same name as the class you are trying, anyway this is not only useful to this purpose.

For example there are multiple classes name **Date** like **Java.sql.Date** and **java.util.Date**, in this case if you need to reference both it's useful to know that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

1. Create a new class and give some another unique name in same package
2. import - `import java.util.*;` or `import java.util.HashMap;`
3. create HashMap as:

`HashMap<Integer,String> map=new HashMap<Integer,String>();` (old verbose way)

or

`HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();`  (better way)

or

`Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();`  (best way)

compile and run

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the Java version you compile to is lower than your JDK.  Make sure the "compiler compliance level", as Eclipse calls it, is high enough.  This happened to me.   The problem happened in Eclipse when my JDK was Java 7, but the compiler compliance level was at 1.4.   On my Eclipse this setting is at Project->Properties->Java Compiler.   I raised the compiler compliance level to 6.0 and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

use `java.util.Map.<String, Integer> cache = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`
and import `import java.util.*;`

Comment: This answer does not bring anything new to the thread, similar solution was already proposed for example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53969107/3157428

Answer (score 0):

- If your using vs code and you forgot to install vs code for java package first do that.
- Change your class name to something different than the name present in your src folder. do not name it HashMap.java.
- import java.util.HashMap;
  there you go it will fix the problem, it did for me.

Answer (score -1):

I did something really stupid to get this error.  You might check.  I named my class "HashMap" lol.  You might check that.