# List to Map using Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert a list of objects to a Map,
I'm trying to do it using Java 8's stream API,
I'm getting 2 errors, 1 on import and 1 in the conversion code of List to Map.

**Error while importing the Map interface -**
 
`The import java.util.Map conflicts with a type defined in the same file.`

**Error in the conversion code -**

```
The type Map is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, BigDecimal>
```

**Following is my code -**

```
public class Developer {

    private String name;
    private BigDecimal sal;
    private int age;

    /**
     * @param name
     * @param sal
     * @param age
     */
    public Developer(String name, BigDecimal sal, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.sal = sal;
        this.age = age;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the sal
     */
    public BigDecimal getSal() {
        return sal;
    }

    /**
     * @param sal
     *            the sal to set
     */
    public void setSal(BigDecimal sal) {
        this.sal = sal;
    }

    /**
     * @return the age
     */
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    /**
     * @param age
     *            the age to set
     */
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Developer [name=" + name + ", sal=" + sal + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

}
```

**My main class -**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Map;

public class Map {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Developer> listDevs = getDevelopers();

        //Error here
        Map<String, BigDecimal> result =  listDevs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Developer :: getName, Developer :: getSal));

    }

    private static List<Developer> getDevelopers() {

        List<Developer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        result.add(new Developer("mkyong", new BigDecimal("70000"), 33));
        result.add(new Developer("alvin", new BigDecimal("80000"), 20));
        result.add(new Developer("jason", new BigDecimal("100000"), 10));
        result.add(new Developer("iris", new BigDecimal("170000"), 55));

        return result;

    }
}
```

**I referred the following question but I am unable to import the Map interface -** 
[The type HashMap is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, Integer>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984915/the-type-hashmap-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments-stri/18984951)

Comment: Do not call your own class Map when you import a class of the same name...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The containing class is called `Map` hence the compilation error. To solve the issue simply rename your class to a different name or use:

```
java.util.Map<String, BigDecimal> result =  
        listDevs.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Developer::getName, Developer::getSal));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the class name, you can also do the following:

```
java.util.Map<String, BigDecimal> result = listDevs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Developer::getName, Developer::getSal));
```